# Remove left margin from wordpress gallery

Tags: css, wordpress, gallery, margin-left

I just started my first blog with wordpress. I'm customizing some of it's features but I can't find the css file for the default gallery block type.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSULE.png) can be seen the difference between image block and gallery block.

Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: can you post your code or share the site url?

Comment: If you could please share the link for this page it would be easier to check the issue and understand the issue. 
You can insert your custom CSS in the default `style.css ` file, don't need to modify the original stylessheet.

Comment: Sure, sorry. http://neposedim.cz/2018/09/03/nedelni-nicnedelani/

Answer (score 0):

There are padding left not margin. so you can use padding-left: 0

```css
.entry-content ul:not(.entry-unordered-list){
  padding-left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@***Kjubu*** Welcome to stack**overflow** !

In your `style.css` file search for the first occurrence of `.wp-block-gallery` in it's properties you will find `padding: 0;` already mentioned just change it to `padding: 0 !important;`.

You will get the desired output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have not found it there so I tried to add it. Nothing happened. This is only gallery code in my style.css

`.gallery-caption{

}`

Comment: the issue is already resolved with the code you added, clear the cache and refresh the page; you will see the effect. I can see it.

Comment: I did it and nothing happened again. Now I think I understand the problem. I use Guttenberg for blocks and it is taking its gallery css instead of style.css. I will try to find it by my own. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Solved: Correct css is located in `gutenberg/build/block-library/style.css`

Comment: I can see the padding removed already. would you mind please trying to open the url on different browser or incognito or different system. It can be cache issue you are not able to see the changes